# How can I use the number range operator on Google Search if there's an extra character present?

Tags: search, range, google-search, ifttt

I'm trying to find the most used recipes on ifttt.com

I'd like to search for something similar to this:

```
[amazon "From $40..$100"]
```

(Which returns a range and works fine.)

This is what I've been trying:

```
[ifttt "23k..999k adds" ]
```

But it seems that the character "k" maybe be interfering with the range operator.

Has anyone had success with this in the past?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to type out the full number for the start and end of the range you want for the search, which would be:

```
[ifttt "23000..999000 adds" ]
```

That works for me... all the recipes I see have >23k adds!

Comment: Awesome thanks! I would upvote this answer but I don't have enough points yet.